# Publish git repository to remote http server

Tags: php, git, automation, github, httpserver

I work on a git repository where we build an php community but i need to show it somewhere so I am looking for a way to automatic upload my files to a remote http server when i push to the repository.

Thanks /Victor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Subversion Git offers a hook mechanism, too. Check out the [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) man page. Basically you just need to write a checkout and deploy script for your PHP application as a post-commit hook.

For github you should have a look at their [webhooks](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) mechanism.

Comment: Please, explain more.
Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: Well if you use your own git repository you can write shell scripts that will be executed after a certain event
(e.g. post-checkout, pre-commit, post-commit) occurrs. That shell script then just needs to checkout the repository
to the server you want to run it. Github (which you tagged this question with) uses a similar mechanism called webhooks
that call a certain URL instead of a shell script.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thank you very much for a well explained answer and the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

If there is no separate git repo on the second server, I would export files from archive:

```
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/target/path/
```

And then used sftp to synchronize with remote server:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST="ftp.example.com"
USER="user"
PASS="pass"
LCD="/var/www/yourdir"
RCD="/www/"
lftp -c "
#debug;
open ftp://$USER:$PASS@$HOST;
lcd $LCD;
cd $RCD;
mirror --only-newer \
       --reverse \
       --verbose \
       --exclude-glob somepattern ";
```

You may automate this process as a build script (e.g. Phing),
our bind as a post commit git hook, like it has been mentioned before.